# Filtering Queries, Adding a field to a query that isn't in the table

Tags: ms-access

I need help with sorting and adding a field to a query that hasn't been made yet.

[image]

For the first bullet, I'm confused at the last part where it asks you to sort by one field, and then within that field, sort again. "Sort the records in ascending order by Region, and within Region, by Product Name." How would I sort it only for Region? or am I not understanding the question...

And for the second bullet, how would I create the field "Extended Price" in a query when it hasn't been created in the table? I'm sure I could handle the rest of that but all I need to know is if there is a way to create a field through query without it being created in the table its based on...

Thank you. (BTW this is a practice question. This practice assignment in no way, shape, or form will benefit my grade)

Comment: You should ask your teacher about guidance on how to solve your homework. You don't anything from having the answers delivered here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query builder to construct SQL. The result should be something like:

`SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Category, UnitsInStock, UnitPrice, SupplierID, SupplierName, Region, UnitsInStock * UnitPrice AS ExtendedPrice FROM Products INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID ORDER BY Region, ProductName;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.product_name,p.category,p.supplier_id,s.supplier_name,s.region,s.unitprice 
 from products p  join supplier  s 
 on  p.supplier_id=s.supplier_id
```

BTW this may work , if you modify accordingly

Comment: I'm a little new to this. Could you possibly write that in plain english instead of in that format. Thank you.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-data-sources-in-a-query-09c75798-8cc7-4877-a8a3-b39572400c19